# Segmentation fault creating a binary search tree in C

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree

I just started learning about trees in C and I keep getting a segmentation fault with my code. The code is meant to create the tree then return the smallest and biggest values in the tree. I have looked at other peoples code and I can't seem to find the mistake that I am making. If anyone can spot it that will be very helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* right;
    struct node* left;
}node;

node* Insert(node* root, int data);
int Min(node* root);
int Max(node* root);
node* GetNewNode(int data);

int main(void){
    int min, max, data, x;
    node* root = NULL;
    printf("how many elements would you like to be in the tree\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        scanf("%i", &data);
        root = Insert(root, data);
    }
    min = Min(root);
    max = Max(root);
    printf("the min value is %i, and the max value is %i\n", min, max);

}

node* Insert(node* root, int data){
    if(root == NULL){
        root = GetNewNode(data);
    }
    else if(data <= root->data){
        root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    else{
        root->right= Insert(root->right, data);
    }
    return root;
}

node* GetNewNode(int data){
    node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

int Min(node* root){
    node* temp = root;
    if(root->left == NULL){
        return root->data;
    }
    else{
        return Min(root->left);
    }
}

int Max(node* root){
    node* temp = root;
    if(root->right == NULL){
        return root->data;
    }
    else{
        return Max(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: `node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));` --> `node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` or `node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));`

Comment: Thats a good catch @BLUEPIXY. Mohammed Would be nice if you execute under GDB and check backtrace, good opportunity to learn debugging as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

to this:

```
node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

You are allocating `sizeof(node *)`bytes which is actually the size of a pointer for you system. What you want is to allocate enough memory to hold **the structure itself** and not a pointer to it. Something like this will work :

```
node* newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node) * sizeof(char));
```